# Masm32, getting bits and bit values

Tags: assembly, bit, masm, masm32

I have a question on how to store a bit from one register to another. Here is the question I need to answer:

Write a sequence of instructions to move to AL bits 5-to-12 from register `edx`.

This is my code so far:

```
     mov edx,8F1h
     ror edx,4
l1:
     ;store this bit in the al register
loop l1
```

I know its not much, but I am completely lost as to how to save the bit and transfer it to another register. After understand this, I can put the loop around it.

Also, code or advice would be great. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It's been ages since I did assembly but why don't you move from edx to al and then do a rotate left 4 times?

Comment: Should be right not left, as in the question. Also, bit numbering is normally zero based, so it should be 5 places not 4. Finally, you should mask off the unneeded bits with `AND`. No loop is needed. Note: you might want to move to `eax` first so as not to destroy `edx`.

Comment: Hints: DL is the low 8 bits of EDX. You probably want to rotate by 5, not by 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you feel lost at that point. You should be looking into copying 8 bits from `edx` (positions 5-12) therefore you just perform a `mov` after the `ror`:

```
 mov edx, 8f1h
 ror edx, 5

 mov al, dl      ;copy lowest 8 bits from edx to al

 rol edx, 5      ;restore edx to 8f1h.
```

As it's full `dl` => `al` register move, you don't need to worry about masking bits or anything. Loop isn't needed either.

**Edit:** Updated the answer to assume 0-based bit count as that's more common. Of course if you don't mind destroying `edx` you can use more straightforward approach:

```
 mov edx, 8f1h
 shr edx, 5

 mov al, dl      ;copy lowest 8 bits from edx to al
```

Comment: I'd never seen a 1-based bit count. Something of that kind would be very confusing when using `BT`, `BTC` or `BTS`.

Comment: I agree, but original question has `ror edx,4` which would be correct for 1-based bit count hence the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I believe vhu's answer is incorrect. This can be seen through the analysis of the order of bit significance in x86 assembly, according to this simple illustration of a 32-bit register (in this case, `edx`):

---

[------------------------------dx-----------------------------] [-------------------------------------------------------------]

[--------------dh-------------] [--------------dl-------------] [-------------------------------------------------------------]

[-------------------------------------------------------------edx------------------------------------------------------------]

31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00

---

Thus, we can infer that bits 5-12 are located in the right side, i.e. the "low order" or "least significant" word (2 bytes) of `edx`. With this said, to store these bits, we must use the `rol` instruction, without the need for a `loop` instruction...

```
mov edx, 8f1h
rol edx, 11           ;(15 - 5) + 1 is our distance from bit 5 to the least significant bit of dx (and also dl)
mov al, dl            ;now al contains bits 5-12 of edx prior to rotation, starting with the least significant bit of al
```

If you want to restore `edx`, just add this at the end of your code:

```
ror edx, 11
```

And since the width of bits 5-12 in `edx` is 8 bytes, there is no need for "bit masks" using the `and` instruction.

Simple success!

Comment: Your figure is incorrect. `dx` is the least significant word (bits 0-15) of `edx`, and `dl` is the least significant byte (bits 0-7) of `dx`. Refer to "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual" Volume 1, page 3-11, figure 3-5.

Comment: vhu's answer is more correct than yours. Your AL gets just zeros from DL. Is this what you want? Hint: the correct value of AL should be 47h.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get all the rotating going on in previous answers.
 What's wrong with a simple:

```
mov al, dl
and al, 0ff0h
```

Comment: I didn't vote, but `ff0h` is 12 bits, so `and al, ff0h` makes no sense (that's if we ignore the fact that `ff0h` probably would be interpreted as a label since it begins with a letter).

Comment: It's not the leading zero but the count of the hex-digits. AL can only hold 8 bits which are **two** hex-digits, not three or four.

Comment: Oh yeah. It's been over a decade. Maybe this?: shr edx, 4  mov al, dl

Comment: `shr`/`mov` is just fine if you don't mind losing content of `edx`.